# Page numbering of custom TOC (DeclareNewTOC) are overlapping textwidth

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I declared a custom TOC for some floats with the following command:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=questiona,%
  name=table,%
  float,%
  listname={Question Overview},%
  tocentrydynnumwidth% <- added
]{qua}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\listoftoc{qua}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{223}
\captionof{questiona}{First Caption with very long text that keeps moving and moving and there is still no end to see}
\setcounter{questiona}{49}
\captionof{questiona}{Foo}
\setcounter{questiona}{999}
\captionof{questiona}{Bar}
\end{document}
```

I have a lot of entries (>50) in the TOC. The entry page numbering is roman, so the page number width can be very wide. I run into the problem that the TOC page numbering now overlaps the text width and I cannot find any switch to change that appropriately.

Is there a way to calculate the right number width automatically or manually tweak the value for my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update (because question has changed)**

You could redefine and `\@pnumwidth` and `\@tocrmargin`. Example:

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@pnumwidth{3em}% default: 1.55em
\renewcommand*\@tocrmarg{4em}% default: 2.55em
\makeatother
```

To restrict this change to the "Question Overview" use

```latex
\makeatletter
\AfterTOCHead[qua]{%
  \renewcommand*\@pnumwidth{3em}% default: 1.55em
  \renewcommand*\@tocrmarg{4em}% default: 2.55em
}
\makeatother
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=questiona,%
  name=table,%
  float,%
  listname={Question Overview},%
  tocentrydynnumwidth%
]{qua}

\makeatletter
\AfterTOCHead[qua]{%
  \renewcommand*\@pnumwidth{3em}% default: 1.55em
  \renewcommand*\@tocrmarg{4em}% default: 2.55em
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\blindtext
\listoftoc{qua}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\captionof{questiona}{A caption}
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{223}
\captionof{questiona}{First Caption with very long text that keeps moving and moving and there is still no end to see}
\setcounter{questiona}{49}
\captionof{questiona}{Foo}
\setcounter{questiona}{999}
\captionof{questiona}{Bar}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Additional remark: **Prerelease of KOMA-Script version 3.27** provides the new options
`tocentrypagenumberwidth` and `tocentryrightmargin` for new declared TOCs:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=questiona,%
  name=table,%
  float,%
  listname={Question Overview},%
  tocentrydynnumwidth,
  tocentrypagenumberbox=\mbox
]{qua}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\blindtext
\listoftoc{qua}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\captionof{questiona}{A caption}
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{223}
\captionof{questiona}{First Caption with very long text that keeps moving and moving and there is still no end to see}
\setcounter{questiona}{49}
\captionof{questiona}{Foo}
\setcounter{questiona}{999}
\captionof{questiona}{Bar}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

---

**Original answer:**

You can use option `tocentrynumwidth=<length>` to adjust the space for the numbers. But with option `tocentrydynnumwidth` the needed width is calculated automatically.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=questiona,%
  name=table,%
  float,%
  listname={Question Overview},%
  tocentrydynnumwidth% <- added
]{qua}
\begin{document}
\listoftoc{qua}
\captionof{questiona}{First Caption}
\setcounter{questiona}{49}
\captionof{questiona}{Foo}
\setcounter{questiona}{999}
\captionof{questiona}{Bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional remark: The calculated value is only used, if it is larger than the value of `tocentrynumwidth` (default 2.3em). So, if option `tocentrydynnumwidth` is set, the value of `tocentrynumwidth` is the minimal width for the numbers.

```latex
% example needs prerelease of KOMA-Script 3.27 (see KOMA-Script website)
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=questiona,%
  name=table,%
  float,%
  listname={Question Overview},%
  tocentrydynnumwidth,
  tocentrypagenumberwidth=10em,% default 1.55em
  tocentryrightindent=4em,% default 2.55em
]{qua}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\blindtext
\listoftoc{qua}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\captionof{questiona}{A caption}
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{223}
\captionof{questiona}{First Caption with very long text that keeps moving and moving and there is still no end to see}
\setcounter{questiona}{49}
\captionof{questiona}{Foo}
\setcounter{questiona}{999}
\captionof{questiona}{Bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are totally right. I asked the wrong question. I was looking for parameter for the page numbering. This column is not inside the textwidth.

Comment: @aronadaal See my updated answer. But it would have been better to ask a new question than to change the original one.